# Please delete a post for me

Tags: support, removal

I recently made [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/382395/as-a-scrum-master-what-am-i-to-my-team), but:

- its answers are unrelated to my question,
- I was not allowed to edit my question,
- I was not allowed to delete my post,
- I received a number of rather unfriendly remarks.

As it is, the answers (while they may be good) simply do not answer my question, and as such **I want it removed**.

Comment: The answers are not unrelated to your question as it is written, at least not to my understanding. They may be unrelated to what you had in mind with your question, but that is a different thing. What is so bad about letting the question now stay where and how it is? You got 3 upvotes and 3 downvotes, giving you a total rep score of +9 for the question, could have been worse.

Answer (score 6):

[I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

> If your question has good answers, though, it's not fair to have those answers removed along with your question: other users put effort into helping you and even if you no longer want the answers, somebody else might. This is why the system prevents you from deleting answered questions most of the time.

Your question was locked because you attempted to vandalize it several times by destroying all the content. The question can be unlocked, if you want to make edits that do not invalidate the existing answers, but will not be deleted since the answers may help someone else.

Since your question has answers, if you are finding that you aren't getting the answers you want, you can try to reformulate and ask a new question. If you aren't sure, you can open a question here on Meta to try to get help from the community to make sure that your question will not only be well-received, but also get the answers that you're looking for (and that, hopefully, will also help other people who have similar questions).

While we're on the subject, I've reopened the question. It is quite clearly not "primarily opinion based" since there are canonical definitions out there.

Comment: If by "vandalize" you mean "delete my own post", then yes. It's got my name on it, and **I** do **not** feel that the answers are at all relevant -- hence my deletion request. As for "those who put in effort", they also put in effort to be unfriendly so I'm okay with losing their contributions.

Comment: @KlaymenDK That's not how Stack Exchange works. You vandalized your post - you made it unreadable by putting nonsense for the body. That is unacceptable and against our rules. You have two options: you can ask for the post to be disassociated from your account) or you can try again to get the answers you need (either with or without the help from the community here on Meta). There is no justification for deletion and edits that either drastically change the meaning of the post or vandalize the post will be rolled back.